# Thread that creates new threads till some threads count

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm learning POSIX threads. The goal is to write program, that creates one thread, which creates two new threads. Every created thread spawns two further threads. Every new thread should sleep, than tells his id(sleep time and ID it becomes as parameter), computing overall sleeping time then starts to create new threads.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_THREADS 10 

pthread_mutex_t wait_time_overall_mutex;
pthread_mutex_t threads_count_mutex;
pthread_mutex_t struct_mutex;

int wait_time_overall = 0;
int threads_count = 0;

struct threads_data {
    int thread_id;
    int time;
};

void* SpawnTwoThreads(void *args) {
    pthread_t t1;
    pthread_t t2;  

    struct threads_data t_args = *(struct threads_data*)args;
    int this_thread_id = t_args.thread_id;
    int this_time = t_args.time;

    printf("t%d: Sleeping for %d\n", this_thread_id, this_time);
    sleep(this_time);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&wait_time_overall_mutex);    
        wait_time_overall = wait_time_overall + this_time;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&wait_time_overall_mutex);

    printf("My id is: %d\n", this_thread_id);
    if (threads_count < MAX_THREADS) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&threads_count_mutex);
            threads_count++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&threads_count_mutex); 

        pthread_mutex_lock(&struct_mutex);  
            t_args.time = rand() % 10;
            t_args.thread_id = threads_count;   
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&struct_mutex);    

        pthread_create(&t1, NULL, SpawnTwoThreads, &t_args);
    }

    if (threads_count< MAX_THREADS) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&threads_count_mutex);
            threads_count++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&threads_count_mutex);       

        pthread_mutex_lock(&struct_mutex);
            t_args.time = rand() % 10;
            t_args.time = threads_count;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&struct_mutex);

        pthread_create(&t2, NULL, SpawnTwoThreads, &t_args);
    }
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);
    printf("Bye from %d\n", this_thread_id);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t t1;
    int t1_wait_time;

    srand(time(NULL));

    pthread_mutex_init(&threads_count_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&wait_time_overall_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&struct_mutex, NULL);

    struct threads_data args;
    args.thread_id = threads_count++; 
    args.time = rand() % 10;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, SpawnTwoThreads, &args);

    printf("In main: waiting for all threads to complete\n");
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    printf("Overall waittime is %d\n", wait_time_overall);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

It creates all threads that i want, but id doesn't unique. I'm becoming output like this:

```
My id is 0
My id is 2
My id is 2
My id is 4
My id is 4
```

It shouldn't be sorted. But at least should be every id unique. Did I done some mistake with mutex? Before creation of new thread I'm updating struct variables. But it doesn't look like that.

Comment: It looks like `threads_count` is a variable that you increment in a mutex block and then later read in a separate mutex block expecting that it wasn't changed in another thread since you incremented it.  Perhaps you should read it within the same mutex block in which you write to it?

You might also consider using atomics instead of mutexes.  You could, for example, use `sync_add_and_fetch` to atomically increment the variable and read back the new value without the use of a mutex. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html

Comment: I've tried to write something like t_args.thread_id = threads_count++;  inside of one mutex lock. That doesn't change anything....

Comment: `threads_count++` does post-increment, so the value stored in `t_args.thread_id` is the value before incrementing.  `++threads_count` would pre-increment so the value stored in `t_args.thread_id` would be `threads_count + 1`.

Comment: Oh, and I also noticed this line: `if (threads_count< MAX_THREADS) {` which reads `threads_count` without mutex protection.

Comment: There is a race condition on `args`, where a thread ID is immediately overwritten by its dual counterpart. Btw in the creation of the 2nd child, `t_args.time = threads_count;` instead of `t_args.thread_id = threads_count;` but that doesn't fix the RC anyway.

Comment: But critical section should be protected only on writing. Am I wrong about it?

Comment: That prevents a non-atomic write to be split by another thread, but the problem is between the writes and the reads. Basically, in parallel what happens is `ID = 2 | ID = 3 ...some time... print ID | print ID`, 3 overwrites the 2, for instance. Do you have to implement a locking system to prevent that? Or you could have an array of `args` (or just allocate a new `arg` per thread)?

Comment: Ok. I see the problem. Second if-block overwrites always id of struct. But how can I prevent something like this? Also i had an Idea to use shared pointer to struct(in my case I'm dereferencing pointer every time at start, to create new instance of struct). But in such case I'm becoming always segmentation fault error.

Comment: The critical section protects both of the two  (or more) consecutive writes, independently. But do you agree that if a protected write B overwrites - a bit after - another protected write A done just earlier, this before A had time to display its ID, there is a problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved it with your advice. Just did it as you said - for every thread new struct instance. Is it really possible to solve without of locks?

Comment: It is possible but it doesn't really make sense, in this case, since this data is specific to a thread...